# Installing oracle in pendrive Linux

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive

I am thinking of installing Pendrive Linux (Ubuntu 12.0), and after that I need to install Oracle in Ubuntu.

Does that mean Oracle get installed on my Pendrive space or Windows Partition?
I am using Windows 8.

If this is not possible, can someone suggest how to install Oracle on a pen drive only? Such that all the contents are in my pen drive, so that I can easily switch machines, only dependency will be pen drive.

Comment: If you look at the screenshots for the [Pendrive universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) you will see that you can set a persistent file at creation to keep changes you make while using it "live". But Oracle? Oracle makes many software... you mean their DB product?

Comment: @illuminÉ:Yes i mean the oracle database

Comment: Grab Oracle VirtualBox and run the Oracle DB Server inside of virtual box. That way you can play with the oracle db without having to mess around with dual booting and all the other hassle.